# Add or edit addresses during multishipping steps in page?

Tags: checkout, cart, address, shipping-address, multishipping

Is there a way to add the ability to edit or add a shipping address in the multishipping checkout process similar to how many onepage checkout extensions do it (example: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magen...-checkout.html). I have placed some form elements in the correct pages, but I'm not sure how best to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Screenshots included;

[image: Multishipping Overview Page]

[image: Multishipping Addresses Page]